# Android EditText in currency format

Tags: android, currency-formatting

When I want to input 100000
then it will 100.000 in EditText (automatically follow the currency format).

Here is the code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_add_items, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
            final EditText add_price = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.add_iprice);
            setCurrency(add_price);

            itemModel= new ModelItems();
            _url = new Url();

            // set prompt_add_category.xmlcategory.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add",
                     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    AddItem(add_price.getText().toString());
                    _url.setItems(itemModel);
            if (add_price.length() == 0) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All data must be filled.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             } 
            else {
              new ParseUrlAsync();
                Itobjt = ParseUrl.getObjectResult(_url.getUrlItem());
                 if (Itobjt.getResult().equals("1")) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success to add item.",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Log.e("URL: ",     _url.getUrlItem());

                    } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot add item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

private void setCurrency(final EditText edt) {
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private String current = "";

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                Locale local = new Locale("id", "id");
                String replaceable = String.format("[Rp,.\\s]",
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                .getSymbol(local));
                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable,
                        "");

                double parsed;
                try {
                    parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    parsed = 0.00;
                }

                NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat
                        .getCurrencyInstance(local);
                formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
                formatter.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
                String formatted = formatter.format((parsed));

                String replace = String.format("[Rp\\s]",
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency()
                                .getSymbol(local));
                String clean = formatted.replaceAll(replace, "");

                current = formatted;
                edt.setText(clean);
               edt.setSelection(clean.length());
               edt.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But in the database it will be saved 100 and will be display 100.

How to make that only in the Edit Text the currency format but in the database will save 100000?
Please help

Comment: Post your database-related code please.

Comment: I meant the code where you insert your data into the database. And please add it to your question, not as a comment.